# How are integrals of non-measurable functions defined in Folland? (Dominated Convergence Theorem)

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, lp-spaces, almost-everywhere

This is the statement of the LDCT stated in Folland:

> The Dominated Convergence Theorem - Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence in $L^1$ such that (a) $f_n\rightarrow f$ a.e., and (b) there exists a nonnegative $g\in L^1$ such that $|f_n|\leq g$ a.e. for all $n$. Then $f\in L^1$ and $\int f = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int f_n$.

It seems like here in order to integrate $f$, we must assume the ambience space to be complete. Otherwise the function $f$ is not measurable. I know that Folland said in the proof that $f$ is measurable up to a null set. However, I am not so sure how this is going to justify the notation "$\int f$". What measure is this integral using?

Results that I think is useful to justify, but not sure how:

[image][image]
[image]

**Update after reading the comments:**

Can I make sense of it this way: We are defining in general the integral $\int_X f := \int_X f \,d\overline{\mu}$ where $f$ is $\overline{\mathcal{M}}$-measurable. Now Prop 2.12 gives us the existence of a $\mathcal{M}$-measurable representative for $f$, we call that representative $g$. Then it make sense to say the following: $\int_X f := \int_X f \,d\overline{\mu} = \int_X g \,d\overline{\mu} = \int_X g \,d\mu$. This chain of equality is always true due to Prop 2.12. Therefore, we can say that when $f$ is only measurable in the completed space and we are integrating it, then we are really integrating the $\mu$-measurable representative using the primal (incomplete) measure $\mu$.

Comment: You are right, but every measure space has a  completion, so $\int f$ is interpreted by going to the completion of the measure space.

Comment: @geetha290krm I see. So we are effective defining this integral to be using the completion of the original measure?

Comment: If $f_n \to f$ pointwise then $f$ is measurable. No completeness needed.

Comment: @copper.hat My mistake. The convergence is a.e. in the statement.

Comment: @Mathematics_Beginner You can let $f$ be any measurable representative, e.g. $f = \limsup_n f_n$.

Comment: @Mason I added an update. Could you check if it makes sense at all? Thank you!

Comment: I believe copper.hat’s point stands. The fact that $f_n \to f$ a.e. implies that $f$ is measurable, does it not?

Comment: @littleO $f$ is measurable iff the measure space is complete. I will attach this result (Proposition 2.11) from Folland in the post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, I'd prefer to avoid going to the completion if possible. It is possible to reword the theorem slightly as follows:

> **Dominated Convergence Theorem.**
>
> Let $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence in $L^1(X,\mathfrak{M},\mu)$ such that
>
> - (a) $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges pointwise a.e on $X$.
> - (b) there is a $g\in L^1$ such that for all $n\in\Bbb{N}$,  $|f_n|\leq g$ a.e.
>
> Then, for every measurable function $f$ for which $f_n\to f$ a.e, we have that $f\in L^1(\mu)$ and $\int_X f\,d\mu=\lim\int_X f_n\,d\mu$.

Note that the conclusion is not vacuous since there does indeed exist such a measurable $f$ (and this is what Folland alludes to, though in a roundabout manner), because of the following simple lemma:

> **Lemma.**
> Let $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of measurable (complex-valued) functions on $(X,\mathfrak{M},\mu)$ which converges pointwise a.e to some function $\phi$. Then, there is a measurable function $f$ on $X$ such that $f_n\to f$ a.e.

To prove this, note that by hypothesis, there is an $N\in\mathfrak{M}$ such that $\mu(N)=0$ and for all $x\in X\setminus N$, we have $f_n(x)\to \phi(x)$. Define $f:X\to\Bbb{C}$ as $f(x):=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(f_n\chi_{N^c})(x)$. Note that each $f_n\chi_{N^c}$ is a measurable function, and this sequence of functions converges pointwise everywhere (if $x\in N^c$ then the sequence converges to $\phi(x)$ by hypothesis, and otherwise to $0$). So, $f$ being the pointwise limit of measurable functions is again measurable, and clearly $f_n\to f$ on $N^c$, and hence pointwise a.e. This completes the proof.

---

What you suggested (introducing extra notation for integrating non-measurable functions) seems fine, but I'm hesitant to pass to the completion unless I really have to, and I'd rather not make new definitions for existing symbols unless it's necessary. In this case, it's not necessary to go this route, since as shown above, it's no loss of generality in assuming $f$ is measurable from the outset. Also, Folland's exact words in the proof were

> $f$ is measurable (perhaps after redefinition on a null set)

so clearly he intended such a redefinition as in the lemma (he mentions proposition 2.12, but I honestly do not see the need for that here, as argued above).

Comment: How is it no loss of generality? If $f_n \to f$ a.e, $f$ is not necessarily measurable, so that its integral is not defined. Of course you can find a function that is equal to $f$ a.e and that its integral is defined, but that doesnt make the integral of $f$ defined.

Comment: @juekai I mean it is *“no loss of generality”* in the sense that if $f_n$ converges pointwise a.e, then there is in fact a measurable $f$ to which it converges pointwise a.e (so would the phrase *“it is not vacuous”* be better for you?), i.e you can add the extra hypothesis of measurability on $f$ with the seemingly weaker assumption on $\{f_n\}$ that it merely converges a.e to **some** $\phi$, so you have assumed less and deduced more.

Comment: also, I never claimed that just because $f_n\to f$ a.e and if $f$ is not measurable, we can/should define the integral of $f$ (ok we **can** make a definition, but I wouldn’t, as I said in my last paragraph)

Comment: anyway, I have reworded the answer to clarify this point.

Comment: So do you mean that when Folland say $f_n \to f$ a.e, what he really meant is that $f_n$ converges a.e rather than to a specific $f$ a.e? Still, $f \in L^1$ doesn't really make sense

Comment: @juekai it ultimately doesn’t matter which $f$ it converges to a.e; I’ve already told you how to rephrase the theorem to avoid any of these issues. Folland is sometimes a terse writer, meaning for many things to occur in a single sentence. He clearly wants the $f$ to be measurable, because his exact words are “$f$ is measurable (perhaps after redefinition on a null set)”. So I suggest you just move on, and not get hung up on every single word Folland uses. Next, I’m not Folland, so I can’t speak 100% on what he did/did not intend.